# Is there a way to use Boost serialization on stl functional

Tags: c++11, serialization, boost, stl, boost-serialization

I have an stl functional `std::function<int(int,int)> fcn_` as a member field of a class. Is there a way to serialize it using boost serialization? If I do the following

```
  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar & fcn_;
  }
```

I got the error

```
/opt/local/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:9: error: 'class std::function<int(int, int)>' has no member named 'serialize'
```

Is there a header file (say something like`<boost/serialization/vector.hpp>`) I can include that implements `serialize` for `std::function`? Or is there an easy way to implement one myself?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can std::function be serialized?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173339/can-stdfunction-be-serialized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tom and sehe's response. After some research, I realized what I had in mind is not really possible in C++ --- it is generally not possible to serialize an `std::function` object. By "serialize", I mean being able to transfer (read/write) the object as a byte stream from one program to another program, or to the same program but a different invocation on the same or a different machine. The links below has more discussion about this topic:

[Serializing function objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338265/serializing-function-objects)

[Can std::function be serialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173339/can-stdfunction-be-serialized)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a look at how Boost serialization works, but here is a possible approach.

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& serialize(std::ostream& out, const std::function<T>& fn)
{
  using decay_t = typename std::decay<T>::type;
  if(fn.target_type() != typeid(decay_t)) throw std::runtime_error(std::string(typeid(decay_t).name()) + " != " + fn.target_type().name());
  const auto ptr = fn.template target<decay_t>();
  out << reinterpret_cast<void*>(*ptr);
  return out;
}

template<typename T>
std::istream& deserialize(std::istream& in, std::function<T>& fn)
{
  using decay_t = typename std::decay<T>::type;
  void* ptr = nullptr;
  in >> ptr;
  fn = reinterpret_cast<decay_t>(ptr);
  return in;
}
```

Please note that this will not work if you are storing lambdas or function objects in your `std::function`s (as per http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target).

A running example can be found [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5418bea9b936be03).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Tom. But I don't think this would work if I write the serialization to a file and reload it in a different program (or the same program at a different invocation). Probably there is no way to do what I have in mind in C++, as discussed here. See the discussion here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338265/serializing-function-objects) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173339/can-stdfunction-be-serialized)

Comment: Interesting links, @YingXiong. Sadly these answers were already dupes and clearly show how your question should be considered a duplicate. Of course, you can ask _follow up_ questions ("How would is serialize it since you can't, using the language core features?")

Answer (score 0):

You could require `my_serializable_function<int(int,int)>` which knows how to self-describe and reconstruct from such a descriptor.

In other words: you *write the code yourself*.

Alternatively, you might look at a scripting engine, which already contains stuff like this (Boost Python, several Lua bindings, v8 engine etc.). Though each comes with their own set of trade-offs and might be overkill.